# Solving problem of assigning people to duties for particular time slot

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to solve the problem where I have number of people with few duties each one and the dates where the various duties have to be performed.
For example:

1. John can be Teacher and Cleaner
2. Margaret can be Accountant and Cleaner
3. Andrew can be an Accountant and Teacher

For that I have time slots:

1. 28/OCT/2023 8:30 we need two Teachers and one cleaner
2. 29/OCT/2023   10:00 we need one Accountant and a Teacher
3. 2/NOV/2023 8:30 we need two Teachers and Accountant
4. 3/NOV/2023   10:00 we need one Accountant and a Teacher
   and so one

I am looking for an algorithm that I can implement in c# that could fulfil this requirement.
I have found similar problem description called `Maximum Flow Problem.` but I don't think that it solves my issue.
Is there any algorithm that could solve the problem described above?

Comment: You have provided insufficient information to solve the problem.  In particular, do the timeslots overlap .  If they do not, then the max flow algorithm can be applied to each timeslot in turn.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Time slots can not overlap.

Comment: Any pointer to give me the example or something similar that describe roughly how the algorithm  applies to my case?

Comment: To allocate your agents to one timeslot using the max flow algorithm take a look at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Allocate

Comment: Can you help me to identified few things Source(Person), Sink(Time slot) and how about functions (Teacher, Cleanr etc)

Comment: All you need is the possibilities.  e.g. for timeslot Saturday 8:30  the first possibility line would be   `l john teacher1` indicating that John can be allocate to the teacher1 job

Comment: The pathfinder code provides the source and sink automatically

Comment: Where do I find the code. The path `https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder.wiki.git` returns me error 404

Comment: I guess you have not used github before.  The code is under the `code` tab at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder

Answer (score 1):

You just need to solve max flow for the constructed graph.

From source to Pi is 1, guarantees that each person can be used once.
From Job_j to Sink as number of given job guarantees that that job can not be used more than that. And each person is connected to the jobs they can do with a link weighted as 1. So that they can contribute to that one. But they can only contribute to pne job as they receive 1 from source.

Since timeslots are not overlapped. You could do the same thing for each tiem slot separately

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To solve this using maximum flow when tasks do not overlap time slots

```
- link agent with every task that the agent can be allocated to
- link source to every agent
- link every task to sink
- set every link capacity to 1
- repeat for each timeslot
```

If you use the pathfinder graph theory library, you only need the first step.  The source, the sink and the link capacities will all be set automatically for you.

The input format for Pathfinder is documented here https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/wiki/Allocate

So, for your Saturday 8:30 timeslot the input required is

```
format alloc
g
l John teacher1
l John teacher2
l John cleaner1
l Margeret cleaner1
l Andrew teacher1
l Andrew teacher2
```

which gives the result

[image]

If the tasks DO overlap timeslots, then the procedure is slightly more complex because for later timeslots, some agents may be unavailable because they are still working on task assigned in earlier timeslots

```
- link every free agent with every task that the agent can be allocated to
- link source to every agent
- link every task to sink
- set every link capacity to 1
- repeat for each timeslot
```

The Pathfinder graph theory library only does one timeslot at a time, which makes it awkward to use for you multiple timeslot problem.  So you will have to use the API and code a more convenient application.  I have put together a C++ application to demonstrate how to do this.

Code to setup the problem:

```
allocator.addTask("teacher");
allocator.addTask("cleaner");
allocator.addTask("accountant");
allocator.addAgent(
    "John",
    {"teacher", "cleaner"});
allocator.addAgent(
    "Margaret",
    {"accountant", "cleaner"});
allocator.addAgent(
    "Andrew",
    {"accountant", "teacher"});
allocator.addSlot(
    "28/OCT/2023 8:30",
    {"teacher", "teacher", "cleaner"});
allocator.addSlot(
    "29/OCT/2023 10:00",
    {"teacher", "accountant"});
allocator.addSlot(
    "2/NOV/2023 8:30",
    {"teacher", "teacher", "accountant"});
allocator.addSlot(
    "3/NOV/2023 10:00",
    {"teacher", "accountant"});
```

Code to run the maximum flow allocation over each timeslot

```
void cAllocator::allocate()
{
    mySolution.clear();

    raven::graph::cGraph g;

    // loop over time slots
    for (auto &slot : mySlot)
    {
        // setup fresh graph for timeslot
        g.clear();
        g.directed();

        // loop over the tasks in timeslot
        for (int task : slot)
        {
            // loop over agents
            for (int agent : findAgentsForTask(task))
            {
                // add link from agent to task agent is able to do
                g.add(
                    myAgents[agent].name(),
                    myTaskType[task]);
            }
        }

        // apply pathfinder maximum flow allocation algorithm to the timeslot
        raven::graph::sGraphData gd;
        gd.g = g;
        mySolution.push_back(alloc(gd));
    }
}
```

The output:

[image]

The complete code for the demo application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/Agents2Tasks

Note that when assigning an agent to a task incurs cost, the Hungarian algorithm can be used to minimize the total cost. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm ) I have implemented the Hungarian algorithm in the latest version of Agents2Tasks

Comment: Is there any executable I could try? or I have to create Visual Studio project for the code and compile myself?

Comment: That would be best.  If you are not familiar with windows tool chains and building, you might find it a challenge.  If  you would prefer that I provide a binary release, let me know.  If you decide to try the build and hit a snag, open an issue in the github repo and we can discuss it in detail.

Comment: Please let me know how you want to proceed.

Comment: @
ravenspoint I have updated little bit my original question. Can you please have a look at it. Are you sure this tool can produce the results I need. Especially assigning time slots. I don't want to waste your time if the goal can't be achieved. If it doesn't cost you too much time you can send me the tool and I can play with it until I understand how I can use it for my purpose.

Comment: Do you want a binary release of the PathFinder application for windows? Yes or no.

Comment: Yes please. I would like to play with it.

Comment: Get the release at https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/releases/tag/v1.0.0

Comment: Added demo app to show how to use PathFinder for your problem

Comment: Sorry. I feel really stupid to ask another question - where is the demo?

Comment: The link is in the last line of my answer.

Comment: There is an executable and source code in form of zip file and tar file but I can't see any demo?

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you spent helping me

Comment: I have implemented the Hungarian algorithm in the latest version of Agents2Tasks

Comment: Thanks for the article "Assign agents to tasks in multiple timeslots". Is there a way to specify that I want for example for particular timeslot two teachers and one cleaner? That would be exact match to what I need ?

Comment: Yes.  In the example I posted the 1st timeslot has two teachers and one cleaner.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. I believe the example given is for doing it programmatically in c++. Can I do the same using pathfinder.exe or I would have to compile the Agents2Tasks cpp project to experiment with that? This sounds really promising.

Comment: I suggest focusing on Agents2Tasks

Comment: In that case can you send me please the Agents2Tasks.exe file. I tried to compile it but have some compiler errors.

Comment: Please open an issue in the Agents2Tasks.  Post the complete build log showing the errors.  Then I can take a look at the problem.

Comment: Hello?  I do not see your issue.  You can open a new issue here https://github.com/JamesBremner/Agents2Tasks/issues/new/choose

Comment: I am getting 404 error when I try to access any of your projects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255841/discussion-between-janci-and-ravenspoint).